# Div Border showing up at wrong place

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to make a 'Site Under Development' page. I want to put border on the div-container which holds the title "under development" and one more line. But the border is showing up on the opposite sides. I have used 'border-top', 'border-left', 'border-style', 'border-color' separately, but it doesn't seem to work. Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

P.S.: Maybe its just a stupid mistake i am making, but i can't spot it :(

Here is the code -

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
#underDevelopment {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 50em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e2e2e2;
  border-top: 2px;
  border-left: 2px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="underDevelopment">
        <div style="color: #ffffff; font-weight:bold;">
          UNDER DEVELOPMENT
        </div>
        <div style="color: #ffffff">
          This Website Is Currently Under Development. It Will Be Updated Soon, Visit Often So That You Donot Miss Anything.
        </div>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   #underDevelopment {
        margin: 0px auto;
        float: left;
        width: 50em;
        padding: 1em;
        background-color: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #e2e2e2;
        border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
```

**Try this css. **

Comment: Thank You! But the code you gave will give me borders on all the sides. I want border just on top and left side :)

Answer (score 1):

**border-top** and **border-left** are shorthand properties that contain the width, style and color of the top and left borders respectively. If you only add the width to those, the browser is going to select defaults for the other properties, overriding your styles before.

To apply just the width of those borders, the properties are **border-top-width** and **border-left-width** respectively.

When you use **border-style** and **border-color** it applies to all corners. Perhaps you want to use **border-width** as shorthand.

```
border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
```

or target each corner's width:

```
border-bottom-width: 0;
border-right-width: 0;
```

Comment: I tried doing that but now it gives me border on all four sides. Is it because I am using both box-shadow and border on the same div? [Sorry for not mentioning this earlier]

Comment: Try `border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2; border-left: 2px solid #e2e2e2;` and remove `border-color: #e2e2e2;`

Comment: Thank You!! I really appreciate that you told me where I was wrong :)

Comment: I updated the answer to expand in what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
#underDevelopment {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 50em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-left: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="underDevelopment">
        <div style="color: #ffffff; font-weight:bold;">
          UNDER DEVELOPMENT
        </div>
        <div style="color: #ffffff">
          This Website Is Currently Under Development. It Will Be Updated Soon, Visit Often So That You Donot Miss Anything.
        </div>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```